# mvc forms authentication landing page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an MVC website that uses Forms Authentication.
I am attempting to add a default landing page to my site ( landing.html ) that each user hitting

http://mywebsite.com for example will be redirected to.

I tried setting the default document in the web.config, but I always get redirected to the Account/Login page.

I do not want to change the login url because that will make the user's whose session has expired to go to the landing page, which is not what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your "default" route.  MVC projects have the following route defined in the RouteConfig class and is called in the Global.asax during application startup.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Just replace "Home" and "Index" with the controller and method you want to use as your default landing page.

Also be sure that if the controller has the [Authorize] attribute added to it then you need to add the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the method you want to use.